# Downloading Latest Blender Version from PPA

Tags: ppa, blender

For a few days I've been looking for a trusted source for the latest version of Blender. I found two commands to download Blender, but the Launchpad page was like this: https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender so I just want to know if there is currently available a good compiled Blender version (it is 2.68a at the moment).

It would be great if someone would help me to get the latest Blender version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error seems to be in launchpad wait for a while till the people make it available. Did you tried to install it using its source code?

Comment: here is a useful link to install blender till the time its not available via ppa if its urgent http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Linux

Comment: thanks for comment, and actually I am using blender for four years but I really don't know what is "Scons",CMake" or building Blender..

Comment: The page [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake) provides info about installing CMake then compliling Blender. It should be noted that if you compile it yourself, you wont get automatic updates like in a PPA so it might be worth waiting for Launchpad to come back online first

Comment: from the blender website: `Blender has two build system, SCons and CMake. Which one to use is a personal preference, and generally they can both build the same features, it's mostly a matter of personal preference.` In my opinion then wait for a while till the maintenance of launchpad is completed then use the ppa to download it. It's available now via ppa the links are now working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The ppa:irie/blender being down for several months now, I have tried
>   to set-up a new version of it. It has 2.73 rc1 on it right now.
>
> https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender
>
> Install it with:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install blender
> ```

PPA set up by [Tishere](https://askubuntu.com/users/349331/tishere).

Comment: is that shutdown temporarily? ah of course, that is why I can't use the link at the moment because I just downloaded Blender 2.68a SVN built two days ago, and now, when I use the same code, terminal says that check your internet connection...

Comment: @Riza It looks like launchpad is back now but I'm not sure for how long

Comment: wow okay, so I started to download it, why it is shutting down like this?

Comment: On Trusty I see `blender-edge : Depends: libopenshadinglanguage1.5 but it is not installable
Recommends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: FYI, apparently because I had previously installed (and `apt-get remove`d the official Wily package for Blender 2.74), it would reinstall this version even after adding Thomas's PPA. To solve the problem, I had to first run `sudo apt-get purge blender`, which seems to destroy leftover configuration files as well... perhaps there is a less dangerous way?